# How to turn off VMware virtual machines goes to "sleep" if no activity?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, ubuntu-10.04, suspend

I have a couple machines, that have close to no activity for a a longer period of time.

And when i try to connect to them with ssh after a week or soo,  its like they have gone into "sleep mode", everything is slow.

Load is not reporting anything,  but basic command in terminal takes ~10seconds to type.

I can restart/warm it up for 15mins and it works fine again.  What's happening?  how can i turn of this "suspend virtual machine" issue?

They are running Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS.   I use VMware ESXi 4.1.0 and vSphere cLient 4.1.0

**Software used is nginx_0.7.65, django 1.3.1, uwsgi-0.9.5.4**

Answer (score 2):

VMware will re-assign memory that hasn't been touched in a long time.

You can prevent this by locking memory on the VM in the resources tab; this reserves physical memory for the VM and it won't be allocated to another VM.

Here is a nice write-up on VMware memory management: http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/perf-vsphere-memory_management.pdf

Comment: hum, will try,  annoying to debug...1 week between runs =)

Comment: Easy to test - just create fake VMs that "need" gaziggabytes of memory, and see if the other VMs memory gets "stolen".

Comment: Turns out,   it did not work.. ;(